# How to list accessible customer list in Google Ads API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-ads-api

We are using Google ads API and we are getting the `refresh_token` and `access_token` from the oauthLibrary.

Now due to some reason (Majorly cause we are using `JavaScript` and there's no library for `JavaScript` officially from Google) we are relying on the REST API.

I want to fetch a list of Accounts attached to the the given access token. (no matter manager or not Manager) I just need the list.

I have tried the following endpoint

`https://googleads.googleapis.com/v1/customers:listAccessibleCustomers`

But I am getting `404 Not found` in that, So I think it is discontinued, Any idea how I can fetch the list through REST_API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to change the v1 for v9. The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/common/others) about the API has a similar sample:

> https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers:listAccessibleCustomers

Comment: Thanks, I actually Figured it out but yeah that was the solution, so Yeah ! great man